# Web-based user editable routing application

Tags: pgrouting, routing, web-service, service-recommendations

I am totally new to web-based GIS (and open source GIS) and am now working on a web-based travel planner using Postgis and Pgrouting with multicriteria costs. I want the end users (the traveler) to be able to decide the cost for different road links.

So I need a web-map service which has vector road links that will be possible to click and edit for logged in users. The edits will then be saved to the postgis database, and the average cost be updated.

Any recommendations for solutions to this?

Is Geoserver a good way to go?
Is Mapfish a good way to go?

Is this a tricky thing or easily done (I am not a programmer or system developer, but willing to learn, though)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm developing an application much like this one. I'm using Django + GeoDjango, with PostGIS and pgRouting..

The deal is that it's much bigger than just connecting a WFS-T service to a published layer.

If I were you, start with simple: learn PostGIS basics and pgRouting basics. These will help you develop a much better application on the long run.

Comment: Thanks George, I was not familiar with GeDjango, but after having a brief look into it, it seems like a nice system. I will learn Postgis and PgRouting basics, and more advanced, but I am kind of in a hurry meeting a deadline in less than three weeks and coming up with a prototype application.

Comment: I was looking into WFS (T) and Geoserver prior to your answer. Is that limiting/constrained compared to GeoDjango. By much bigger, I suppose you mean that it needs quite a bit of database work

Answer (score 1):

You need a WFS (T) 'Transactions'  service to edit features - GeoServer/Mapserver can provide this with Openlayers

An Example is here:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html